# Fatal package error upon trying to run a launch file using roslaunch

Tags: dynamic, ros, robotics, catkin, gazebo-simu

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bih3k.png)

Hello,

I am attempting to launch a URDF file using a launch file (that includes arguments to launch an empty world with my URDF in it). I sourced my catkin_ws directory to the simulation_ws directory, where I am attempting to launch my file from. When I use the roslaunch command to launch the file, initially it starts the process of running the file, and then gives me an error stating that "Package[] does not have a path". May I have some help understanding what this means? Could it potentially be an issue with the arguments I have in the launch file? I am willing to provide more details if needed.

Thanks.

Launch File:
[Launch File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biThw.png)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include my launch file